# Gradle downloads old compile dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, dependencies, dependency-management

I am using spring-boot and gradle. I want to use latest selenium version, however half of compile dependencies, including drivers, are somehow 3.14 version. I tried invalidating caches, `./gradlew clean build`, `./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies`, but it doesn't help. My older project has the same dependencies (but no spring-boot) and I this issue is not present.

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.7'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'xxx.xxxxxx'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.1.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng
    testImplementation 'org.testng:testng:7.5'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:4.5.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager
    implementation 'io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:5.1.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.javafaker/javafaker
    implementation 'com.github.javafaker:javafaker:1.0.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core
    testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.22.0'

}

test {
    useTestNG()

    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat(TestExceptionFormat.FULL)
    }

    systemProperties(System.getProperties())
}
```

[image: old dependencies]

Comment: It could be an issue with IntelliJ. Try to check versions using `gradle -q dependencies`.

Comment: @Alex here is part of log:
+--- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.1.4
|    +--- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:4.1.4 -> 3.141.59
|    +--- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:4.1.4 -> 3.141.59

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot manages the versions for Selenium, so in your case you only specified the version for `selenium-java`, all other versions were managed by Spring Boot. To properly update all Selenium dependencies, you have to override the property for the Selenium version:

```
ext['selenium.version'] = '4.1.4'
```

and remove the version from the selenium-java entry:

```
implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java'
```

You can find all available properties for libraries managed by Spring Boot in the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.7/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix.dependency-versions.properties